# Validation message is displaying on page load after upgrade of application to angular13 issue?

Tags: angular, primeng

Validation message should display later when I don't give any input. But it is coming as soon as page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Add form.touched method to Validation messages which will display it only when you start to fill that field.

```
<label class="mb-1" for="userName">UserName</label>
                    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" class="form-control"
                        [class.is-invalid]="form['userName'].invalid && form['userName'].touched" formControlName="userName"
                        placeholder="Enter Username">
                    <div *ngIf="form['userName'].touched && form['userName'].invalid" class="text-danger">
                        <small *ngIf="form['userName'].errors?.['required']">Username is Required</small>
                     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can show the validation message when the form field **touched**
> and **dirty** property

> Example form group

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
   toDo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30)]]
});
```

> Example HTML

```
<input 
    id="toDo" 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="What is it you want to do?"
    formControlName="toDo"
    [class.valid]="formGroup.get('toDo').valid && 
        (formGroup.get('toDo').dirty || formGroup.get('toDo').touched)"
    [class.invalid]="formGroup.get('toDo').invalid && 
        (formGroup.get('toDo').dirty || formGroup.get('toDo').touched)" />



<div *ngIf="formGroup.get('toDo').invalid && 
            formGroup.get('toDo').errors && 
            (formGroup.get('toDo').dirty || formGroup.get('toDo').touched)">
        <small class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="formGroup.get('toDo').hasError('required')">
            This field is required.
        </small>
        <small class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="formGroup.get('toDo').hasError('minlength')">
            The minimum length for this field is {{formGroup.get('toDo').errors.minlength.requiredLength}} characters.
        </small>
        <small class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="formGroup.get('toDo').hasError('maxlength')">
            The maximum length for this field is {{formGroup.get('toDo').errors.maxlength.requiredLength}} characters.
        </small>
    </div>
```

> **dirty** property will return true if the element’s contents have been changed.
>
> **touched** property will return true if the user has visited the element.